# MSSQL Regular expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

I have the following REGEX: ^[-A-Za-z0-9/.]+$

This currently checks whether the value entered into a textbox matches this. If not, it throws an error.

I need to check whether anything has already gone into the database that doesnt match this.

I have tired:

```
 SELECT * FROM *table* WHERE ([url] NOT LIKE '^[-A-Za-z0-9/.]+$') 
 SELECT * FROM *table* WHERE PATINDEX ('^[-A-Za-z0-9/.]+$', [url])
```

**UPDATE**

So after a bit of research I've realised I don't think I can use REGEXP.

I thought I could do something like this? Its not giving me the expected results but its running unlike anything else. Can anyone spot anything wrong with it?

```
SELECT *, 
  CASE WHEN [url] LIKE '^[-A-Za-z0-9/.]+$' 
    THEN 'Match' 
    ELSE 'No Match' 
  END Validates
FROM 
  *table*
```

Comment: Are you using MSSQL or MySQL?  They are two, different, competing RDBMS products from different suppliers and which have different syntax.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is what I have used in the end:

```
SELECT *, 
  CASE WHEN [url] NOT LIKE '%[^-A-Za-z0-9/.+$]%' 
    THEN 'Valid' 
    ELSE 'No valid' 
  END [Validate]
FROM 
  *table*
  ORDER BY [Validate]
```

Comment: I am very sure the answer does not work as intended, because MS-SQL supports only a very limited subset of RegExp like operators: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187489(v=sql.105).aspx, hence the expression provided in [] matches one single character from the set ^-A-Za-z0-9/.+$ and the rest is consumed by % which will match any string in LIKE expression.

Comment: @Mr.Napik - The idea is sound though it is collation dependent whether or not it actually works as written. `^` acts as a negation. So instead of saying  "check every character matches the pattern" it checks that there are no characters that don't match the pattern. It probably needs a binary collate clause to actually work as intended though. e.g. see `SELECT char(number) FROM master..spt_values WHERE type='P' and number between 1 and 255 and CHAR(number) NOT LIKE '[^-A-Za-z0-9/.+$]'  COLLATE Latin1_General_Bin` with and without it.

Answer (score 21):

> **Disclaimer:** The original question was about MySQL. The SQL Server answer is below.

## MySQL

In MySQL, the regex syntax is the following:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE (`url` NOT REGEXP '^[-A-Za-z0-9/.]+$')
```

Use the `REGEXP` clause instead of `LIKE`. The latter is for pattern matching using `%` and `_` wildcards.

---

## SQL Server

Since you made a typo, and you're using SQL Server (not MySQL), you'll have to create a user-defined CLR function to expose regex functionality.

Take a look at [this article](http://web.archive.org/web/20160307210334/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlclr/archive/2005/06/29/regex.aspx) for more details.

Comment: I am receiving 'an expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected' do I need to reference anything else?

Comment: Hmm, I think it may be related to Phylogenesis' comment... Don't use `[...]` to escape column names, that's T-SQL syntax. Either drop them if possbile or use backticks (`)

Comment: I've altered it, to the above code. I am now receiving: Incorrect syntax near 'REGEX'. expecting between in or like. I've googled this and it seems that its a type cast error?

Comment: I'm starting to wonder whether I can in actual fact use REGEXP in SQL Management Studio 2012

Comment: Are you sure you are using MySQL and not MS SQL? SQL Server Management Studio is generally used with the latter.

Comment: @Clare AHA! Yeah, that's a totally different thing! In MSSQL you need to use a [CLR function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2kae45k.aspx) to use regexes.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski, the link you have provided in answer is not valid at the moment. Can you provide the valid link

Comment: @JitendraPawar I changed the link to use the wayback machine

Answer (score -2):

**As above the question was originally about MySQL**

Use `REGEXP`, not `LIKE`:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE ([url] NOT REGEXP '^[-A-Za-z0-9/.]+$')
```

Comment: @Azimuth Regular expression information on SQL Server can be found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/scripting/search-text-with-regular-expressions

Comment: @Matt The link you provided refers to __editing__ the query, rather than valid syntax of SQL Server. More important thing is that even in SQL Server 2017 running similar query returns 
`An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'REGEXP'.` error - I assume there is no such keyword yet.

Comment: Yes, as @bjauy pointed, there is no such keyword as `REGEXP`. So please update your answer with correct SQL code.