# Caret in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Consider the below query:

```
Select  
    Case when left(‘152rew’, 5) not like ‘%[^A-Za-z]%’ 
       then ‘true’ 
       else ‘false’ 
    end
```

How ^ this is working in above SQL statement as it is returning false.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: asked before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29206404/mssql-regular-expression

Comment: Your like regex logic is asking if the input is _not_ like a string which contains at least one non letter.  Clearly, the left-5 contains a digit, so the assertion is false.

Answer (score 1):

In the [LIKE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql) syntax used in SQL Server you can indeed use a character class.

For example:

```
x LIKE '%[A-Z]%'
```

Which would be true if x contains at least 1 letter.

Btw, this example assumes a case-insensitive collation.

The `^` at the start of the `[...]` is used as a negation of that.

F.e.

```
x LIKE '%[^A-Z]%'
```

Which would be true if x contains at least one character that is NOT a letter.

So then when negating the negation:

```
x NOT LIKE '%[^A-Z]%'
```

It's like looking for x that only contain letters, or is an empty string. In other words: x most NOT contain a character that is NOT a letter.

But something as ‘152rew’ also contains digits, so it's false.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select  Case when left('152rew',5) not like '%[^A-Za-z]%' then 'true' else 'false' end
```

`left('152rew',5)`  would be `152re` which doesn't match the regex `'%[^A-Za-z]%'`
because:

`'%[^A-Za-z]%'` would be matched against the words that contain letters only (A-Z) since it has `a-z` that would make it case-insensitive so it will accepts all the letters from A to Z i.e capital as well as small.

As it doesn't match `'%[^A-Za-z]%'` so true is returned.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server allows character classes in `LIKE`. `'%[A-Za-z]%'` means "contains a letter". `^` negates the expression. `'%[^A-Za-z]%'` means "contains a non-letter".

Hence your `CASE` expression is this in pseudo code:

```
if '152re' doesn't contain a "non-letter"
     then 'true'
     else 'false'
end if
```

Or simpler:

```
if '152re' contains a "non-letter"
     then 'false'
     else 'true'
end if
```

`1`, `5`, and `2` are not letters, so the string contains a "non-letter"; the expression returns 'false'.